# How to include new module in Joomla k2 item.php

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla-k2

I want to include one new module position inside the item.php of K2. Is it possible?

I want to add advertisement in that module (diff in different categories) .

This module should align left in the article and item image should align right in the article.

Please help me achieving this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load a module inside an article, simply give the module a custom position then add this code inside the article editor:

```
{loadposition xxx}
```

xxx = the custom position you gace the module.

If you are wondering how to give the module a custom position, then don't worry. 
Instead of click Joomla 1.5's dropdown or Joomla 2.5's button, click inside the input box and type your own position.

You can then align the module as you wish, like you would normal text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your directions. I have done the same (created new position test and assigned one module to this position), but from front end its showing {loadposition test}
Whats the issue ?

Comment: @SrikanthG: this sometimes happens when the module is disabled so make sure it's enabled. Other than that, the only thing I could do is take a look for you if you would be willing to create an admin account for me and send the details via e-mail.

Comment: I found the issue.  In K2 Joomla 2.5 {loadposition "mod name"} not working.  I installed modules anywhere plugin whcih had syntax as {modulepos "modname"}  . Its working fine.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: ah ok, wasn't aware you hade "modules anywhere" :) glad you got it working